# When using the Influence action, can you influence a hex adjacent only to the newly claimed hex?

Tags: eclipse

The Influence action allows a player to move up to two Influence Discs to a hex that is "adjacent to a hex where you have a disc or a Ship."

In a case where the first Influence Disc is moved to an adjacent sector, it is possible to move the second Influence Disc to a hex that is only adjacent to the hex just claimed?  Or must both sectors be adjacent to hexes controlled at the beginning of the Influence action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read and understood you are allowed to move it to a hex adjacent hex to the hex just claimed. For instance it would be perfectly legal to do the following:

Start of influence action ( | is a partial wormhole and |   | is an empty hex)

| A || B || C ||   ||   |

Move the first influence disc:

| A ||   || C || B ||   |

Move the second influence disc:

|   ||   || C || B || A |

Hope that was an understandable schematic :)

Comment: This is how we played it too.

Comment: And from now on this move will be called "the galactic hoppity hop"